Sleep standby mode jetson
Hi I m stuck with sleep standby mode on jetson recomputer agx orin after attempting to install jetpack that already present on the device under the version 5.1.2 and installing a new version led to standby mode unable to boot the device on ubuntu anymore and don t know how to quit the mode or correct the failure even on internet there is no similar problem
I tried to change power supplies but I don’t think this is the cause of problem I do not have any other choice
